# Detect gesture accelerometer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, accelerometer

I'm creating an iPhone application.
My application needs to detect the movements of the accelerometer and report the case of movement by the user.
In practice I have to constantly check that the coordinates received from accelerometer are equal to the coordinates saved in my movement.
My problem is that its implementation is not simple because I know there are many factors that create difficulties.
Someone knows a tutorial or guide to propose.
I also welcome suggestions ...
Thank you very much

Comment: what have you tried till now? have you checked other accelerometer questions on stackoverflow for some pointers?

Comment: yet I can recognize a positions and a number of positions locations constant.
My problems are movements

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this paper](http://www.truststc.org/reu/10/Reports/DasGreenPerezMurphy_Paper.pdf) as a starting point.

It shows detection of a user walking, running, walking up or down stairs or standing still. Even though it's based on Android the principle will be the same.